# IP Address SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, remote-access, static-ip-address

I work remotely and travel a lot for work. When I am at home, I have no problem accessing my instance of SQL Server hosted by my company on AWS. The SQL Server  instance is currently configured to only accept connections from ONE IP address and as it changes I lose my connection. Whenever I travel I cannot access SQL Server and when I come home, sometimes my IP address changes and I also cannot access from home.

I am sure this is an issue others have had. Can anyone suggest a solution? Whether it is from the DB side or client side?

Thank you,

- dave

Comment: Had a similar issue and used Private VPN with a Static IP ... nominal cost

Comment: Are you sure it's a SQL Server restriction? Some months ago I tried to restrict incoming connections by IP address and [learnt](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/143334/allow-remote-access-only-from-certain-ip-addresses) it isn't possible (you need a firewall for that).

Comment: you cannot acces because your ip address changed or because the ip address of the server changed ?

Comment: @guidoG because my ip address keeps changing

Comment: @JohnCappelletti what service did you use? the private VPN I have looked into assign IPs randomly

Comment: I used vpnstaticip.com  very satisifed.  There are many out there even cheaper  Just google "private vpn static ip"

Comment: Also used them for my daughter when she was in China --- as you may know, they have many restrictions

Comment: Than the solution mentioned by John Cappelletti should work

Comment: thank you guys. very helpful

Comment: just to come full circle - i signed up for PureVPN with the dedicated IP feature which is only $12 a month ... Wish I knew this was so easy earlier ... Thanks again!